# How to pass params by html or php to an html embed swf?

Tags: php, html, flash, parameters

Hello guys how are you doing? Fine i hope.

Well i'm trying to make a non javascript version of a site and there is this swf client that runs by a javascript library which sets sizes and passes params.

Here is some code:

```
swfobject.embedSWF(KingGame._game_url, "flashContent", KingGame._flash_width, KingGame._flash_height, "10.0.0", false, {"param": KingGame._flash_params}, paramtrs);
```

This is the line where swfobject framework calls the swf and is passes this param to it which is an enormous xml file converted to a string i supose.

So now im trying to use something like:

```
<object width="1000" height="1000">
    <param name="params" value="<?=urlencode($xml_config)?>">
    <embed src="<?=$url?>" width="1000" height="1000">
    </embed>
</object>
```

But it's not working i don't know how to pass this params with php or html, i'm searching but finding nothing, does anyone knows if that is possible at least?

Thanks

Comment: Does anyone really have Flash Player and not JavaScript enabled?

Comment: Anyhow, don't you also need a param for the movie source, and need to include the params for the embed tag? Looks like you only have on one for each tag. Remember the embed tag is a fallback for browsers not supporting object.